# Why isn't my image being mapped to my React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The title seems to be mapped fine but the images are not. I went over the code a couple of times but I can't find out what's wrong. Let me know what changes I have to make. The author of the tutorial did use class based components and I converted it to functional components but regardless the code should display the images but it isn't.

```
// directory-data.jsx

export const sections = [
  {
    title: 'hats',
    imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/cvpntL1/hats.png',
    id: 1,
    linkUrl: 'shop/hats',
  },
```

```
// menu-item.component.jsx

import React from 'react'
import './menu-item.styles.scss'
const MenuItem = ({ title, imageUrl }) => (
  <div
    style={{
      backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`,
    }}
    className='menu-item'
  >
    <div className='content'>
      <h1 className='title'>{title}</h1>
      <span className='subtitle'>Shop Now</span>
    </div>
  </div>
)

export default MenuItem
```

```
// directory.component.jsx

import React from 'react'
import { sections } from './directory-data'
import MenuItem from '../menu-item/menu-item.component'
import './directory.styles.scss'

export const Directory = () => {
  return (
    <div className='directory-menu'>
      {sections.map(({ title, imageURL, id }) => (
        <MenuItem key={id} title={title} imageUrl={imageURL} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
// homepage.component.jsx

import React from 'react'
import './hompage.styles.scss'
import { Directory } from '../../components/directory/directory.component'

const Homepage = () => (
  <div className='homepage'>
    <Directory />
  </div>
)

export default Homepage
```

Comment: Hard to say for sure without a working example, but you have a typo in your sections.map - `imageURL ` should be `imageUrl` (last two letters lowercase)

Comment: Any errors in console? have you tried logging `imageUrl` in your `MenuItem` component? Don't see an obvious error in your code.

Comment: Ah...sure what @D-Money said. In `sections` the key is defined as `imageUrl` not `imageURL`. Your deconstruction fails and returns undefined.

Comment: The smallest amount of debugging would have shown you that `imageURL` was undefined.

Comment: I changed the spelling and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your object looks like this:

```
{
 title: 'hats',
 imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/cvpntL1/hats.png',
 id: 1,
 linkUrl: 'shop/hats',
},
```

as you can see the property name is `imageUrl`

in your map function you are trying to take a property named `imageURL`

```
{
   sections.map(({ title, imageURL, id }) => (
    <MenuItem key={id} title={title} imageUrl={imageURL} />
 ))}
```

**the fix is change the `imageURL` to `imageUrl` when you deconstruct the object**

Comment: I changed the spelling and it still doesn't work